# Exception thrown by an interceptor doesn't go to the exception handler.

Tags: java, exception, struts2, struts, interceptor

There's an issue I've experienced this day. I have an interceptor that begins and commits a Hibernate transaction and it may throw an exception on commit (`org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException` for instance). That is, it can throw an exception but exception doesn't get to the handler. I thought there's an issue in my code. But then I wrote a simple test and here it is

Package definition in `struts.xml`:

```
<package name="basicstruts2" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="dummy" class="test.TestInterceptor"/>

        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="dummy" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="myStack"/>

    <global-results>
        <result name="exception" type="chain">exceptionHandler</result>
    </global-results>

    <global-exception-mappings>
        <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception" />
    </global-exception-mappings>

    <action name="test" class="test.TestAction">
        <result>result.jsp</result>
    </action>

    <action name="exceptionHandler" class="test.ExceptionHandler">
        <result>DebugErrorPage.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

**`TestAction.java`:**

```
package test;

public class TestAction extends ActionSupport {

    private BusinessLogic logic = new BusinessLogic();

    public String execute() {
        logic.test();
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

**`TestInterceptor.java`:**

```
package test;

public class TestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public String intercept(ActionInvocation arg0) throws Exception {
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = arg0.invoke();
            boolean flag = true;
            if (flag) throw new RuntimeException("qwerty");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception catched in interceptor, rethrowing " + e);
            throw e;
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

**`ExceptionHandler.java`:**

```
package test;

public class ExceptionHandler extends ActionSupport {

    private Exception exception;

    public void setException(Exception e) {
        exception = e;
        System.out.println("setting exception");
    }

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("exeption in handler " + exception);
        return SUCCESS;
    }

}
```

**`BusinessLogic.java`:**

```
package test;

public class BusinessLogic {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test logic");
//      boolean flag = true;
//      if (flag) throw new RuntimeException("qwerty");
    }
}
```

So, console output :

```
test logic
exception catched in interceptor, rethrowing java.lang.RuntimeException: qwerty
```

BUT if an exception is thrown by BusinnesLogic, we can uncomment code:

**`BusinessLogic.java`:**

```
package test;

public class BusinessLogic {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("test logic");
        boolean flag = true;
        if (flag) throw new RuntimeException("qwerty");
    }
}
```

and comment out code in interceptor:

```
@Override
        public String intercept(ActionInvocation arg0) throws Exception {
            String result = null;
            try {
            result = arg0.invoke();
        //  boolean flag = true;
        //  if (flag) throw new RuntimeException("qwerty");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("exception catched in interceptor, rethrowing " + e);
                throw e;
            }
            return result;
        }
```

output will be:

```
test logic
exception catched in interceptor, rethrowing java.lang.RuntimeException: qwerty
setting exception
exeption in handler java.lang.RuntimeException: qwerty
```

And we will see the error page.

So, can anybody give a good explanation of this behavior? What's the point of putting the exception interceptor at the top of the default struts stack if it can't handle exceptions that was thrown by other interceptors? and why??
I would really appreciate for a good answer.

**EDIT:**
There is a code I have a problem with:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation arg0) throws Exception {
    String result = null;

    try {

        sf.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

        result = arg0.invoke();

        sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (StaleObjectStateException staleEx) {
        if (sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
            sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
        }
        throw staleEx;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        try {
            if (sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                sf.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
            }
        } catch (Throwable rbEx) {
        }

        // Let others handle it... maybe another interceptor for exceptions?
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }

    return result;
}
```

What should be done if I want handle exceptions thrown on `commit()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exception is thrown by `TestInterceptor` *after* the action invocation and result rendering.

From the note on the [Writing Interceptors page](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/writing-interceptors.html):

> Keep in mind that invoke will return after the result has been called (eg. after you JSP has been rendered), making it perfect for things like open-session-in-view patterns. If you want to do something before the result gets called, you should implement a PreResultListener.

Comment: thanks, I thought I got it, but I didn't have success in trying this. I edited my question by adding a real code. Can you provide some example to fix my issue?

Answer (score 2):

Core Functionality of ExceptionMappingInterceptor

> This interceptor forms the core functionality of the exception handling feature. Exception handling allows you to map an exception to a result code, just as if the action returned a result code instead of throwing an unexpected exception. When an exception is encountered, it is wrapped with an ExceptionHolder and pushed on the stack, providing easy access to the exception from within your result. Note: While you can configure exception mapping in your configuration file at any point, the configuration will not have any effect if this interceptor is not in the interceptor stack for your actions. It is recommended that you make this interceptor the first interceptor on the stack, ensuring that it has full access to catch any exception, even those caused by other interceptors.

Example code:

```
   <xwork>
     <package name="default" extends="xwork-default">
         <global-results>
             <result name="error" type="freemarker">error.ftl</result>
         </global-results>

         <global-exception-mappings>
             <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="error"/>
         </global-exception-mappings>

         <action name="test">
             <interceptor-ref name="exception"/>
             <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
             <exception-mapping exception="com.acme.CustomException" result="custom_error"/>
             <result name="custom_error">custom_error.ftl</result>
             <result name="success" type="freemarker">test.ftl</result>
         </action>
     </package>
   </xwork>
```